# jQuery change selected value and submit form basd of localStorage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a problem. I have select with name category and have code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('category') !== null) {
  $('select[name=category]').val(localStorage.getItem('category')).trigger('change');
  $('.form-search').submit();
}
```

If in Local storage I have id, then I change selected value in select. But How I can submit this form? My code is not working, because page reloading many times..

MY form:

```
<form method="get" class="form-search">
....
      <select name="category">
            <option value="1">Auto</option>
            <option value="2">Sport</option>
            ...
      </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `action` of form to this page?

Comment: @Mohammad nope..

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: So why **page reloading many times**. action page redirect to this page?

Comment: @Mohammad I updated question, yes on this page

Comment: Your code submits the `form` correctly but next time on page load your browser still have the `localstorage` value so the above `JS` code execute again and again that's why your page reload many times.

Comment: if you want to prevent reloading you go to add this to submit call .`submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the form hasn't `action`, browser submit form to this page and page reloaded and because you don't removed `localStorage` the code runned again. So you should remove localStorage `category` before submitting form.

```
var category = localStorage.getItem('category');
if (category !== null) {
  $('select[name=category]').val(category).trigger('change');
  localStorage.removeItem('category');
  $('.form-search').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the trigger

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('category') !== null) {
 $('select[name=category]').val(localStorage.getItem('category'));
    $('.form-search').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Check code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wfqtx2?file=index.js)